# Can I get the game center application back on my MacBook Air

Tags: game-center

The previous owner of my MacBook Air seems to have deleted my game center application. Is there any way I can get that back?

Comment: You're using the same installed system as when a previous owner had it?!? Can we spell key-logger? NEVER use a second hand machine without wiping it first.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling OS X from the Recovery Partition. Turn off your computer, hold down Command and R while you turn it on again, and then go through the Reinstall OS X process. Apple Support has an article about it [here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718).